# How does incarnum multiclassing work?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, multi-classing, meldshaping

For example: I multiclass Incarnate/Totemist. Do they share a pool of melds/essentia/chakras, or are they somehow separate (such as it is with initiators)?

I can't seem to find a rules reference to this, but it seems rather critical.

Comment: @HeyICanChan Thanks for the edit; did not spot the meldshaping tag.

Comment: You're welcome. Had I not made the tag myself a while back, I would've missed it, too. `;-)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The rules for multiclass meldshapers are found on page 20, in the heading cunningly titled “Multiclass Meldshapers.” The introduction to the classes chapter, rather than the incarnum chapter in general, is kind of a surprising place for this information in my opinion, but then *Magic of Incarnum* is notorious for hiding things.

Quick overview:

- You only have one essentia pool, and essentia from various classes stack.
- Your soulmelds are separate and independent. If you are a 4th-level incarnate/2nd-level totemist, you can shape 4 soulmelds from the incarnate list and 3 soulmelds off the totemist list.
- The meldshaping class features themselves also remain independent. In the above case, the 4 incarnate soulmelds use Wisdom to determine their saving throw, while the 3 totemist soulmelds use Constitution.
- Chakras, too, are separate, both the limits on how many soulmelds can be bound to a chakra as well as which charkas are open.

  - The incarnate soulmeld you bound in the above case could only be bound to the crown chakra; the totemist soulmeld you bound in the above case could only be bound to the totem chakra.
  - And you could not choose to forgo a chakra bind from one class in order to bind another soulmeld from another class—for example, if the above meldshaper had Open Least Chakra (feet), he could bind a soulmeld (either incarnate or totemist) to his feet, but he could not, for example, choose to bind 0 incarnate soulmelds in order to bind a totemist soulmeld to each of his feet and totem chakras.
- Class features that expand soulmelds’ essentia capacity apply only to the soulmelds shaped as part of that class. The above character would have a base essentia capacity of 2, but his incarnate soulmelds would have a capacity of 3, as would the totemist soulmeld bound to his totem.

Note that there are still some aspects of this that are unaddressed. For instance, it’s not clear if you could shape *lammasu mantle* twice in the above situation, once as an incarnate and again as a totemist (the basic effects wouldn’t stack in any event, but arguably you could then bind it to both your arms and your shoulders to enjoy both bind effects).